# Get all data from XML tag using XSL

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xpath

Hi I have an XML data like

```
<data>
      <Id>T2351</Id>
      <Name>Sam</Id>
</data>
```

and I am using an XSL to extract the data from each ID and Name tags and put it in an csv file. MY XSL code looks like this,

```
<xsl:template match="/"> Id,Name
<xsl:for-each select="//data">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Id,',',Name,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But the problem is sometimes in the data the Name has multiple values like "Sam,Tien" and whenever a comma is present the data gets split into different columns in the csv which I have to stop. I am very new to XSL and hence unable to figure out what the solution should be to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach for values that contain commas in CSV is to enclose the value in quotation marks.

For your case that could look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">Id,Name
  <xsl:for-each select="//data">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Id, ',&quot;', Name, '&quot;&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, just clarifying, so the only change that I need to do is to edit my ',' to '," ' ? i.e. put a double quotation inside and one at the end before the &#xA? Because I'm encountering error after doing that change.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Updating my answer.

Comment: Its not working if data is unavailable for Name field. In my XSL code the row is left blank when data not found.

Comment: @timukh And before you were adding the quotes, those rows were not left blank?

Comment: When I'm using my concat(Id,',',Name,'&#xA;') code, the rows are left blank if the node "Name" doesnt exist or the data is blank but after using &quot; the rows that doesn't exist are overwritten by the next available node i.e. the next Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following , It may help you.

```
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., ', ')]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked

```
<xsl:template match="/">Id,Name
  <xsl:for-each select="//data">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',Id,'&quot;,&quot;',Name,'&quot;&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Only this way was the csv able to skip the comma's present within the values of any field